# How does Shodan crawl internet-connected devices?

Tags: web-application, databases, server

I wonder how [Shodan](http://www.shodanhq.com) crawls internet-connected devices and adds them to its database. I know Google, for instance, finds new websites by following links in websites it already found, but that strategy won't work with internet-connected devices because they don't link to one another.

What method does Shodan follow?

Comment: I dont know why people vote a question down without a comment. This question is legit and so I voted up to balance it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are only about four billions of possible IPv4 addresses, so trying them all is feasible, with enough bandwidth. There are [available tools](https://zmap.io/) for that.

Shodan themselves document in their [FAQ](http://www.shodanhq.com/help/faq) that they use some custom code:

> A home-grown, distributed port scanner was developed for this project.

"Distributed" here means that connections are made from several machines, which seems not an issue since Internet-wide scanning is, by definition, an [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problem.

---

A related case is the so-called [Internet Census 2012](http://internetcensus2012.bitbucket.org/paper.html) in which some unknown people repeatedly scanned for some vulnerable hosts (typically home routers still configured to accept default admin credentials) and temporarily hijacked the said systems to enlist them in a whole Internet scan on "most common ports" -- that's a case of a self-replicating botnet. They say that they reached 420000 clients under their control. For a complete Internet scan, each client only has 10000 IP addresses to try, so this can be done quite discreetly (say, 3 probed IP per second for an hour).